# Interacting with google chrome browser from WCF service

Tags: wcf, internet-explorer, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension

I have a local WCF service which needs to communicate with a web browser.
It has to do the following

- Scroll the page
- Add cookies
- Open new tabs
- Etc.

I thought to use one of those; Chrome, IE, Firefox and create an extension which would forward my WCF messages to a browser.

Have you got any suggestion which browse has a richer API, easier to use, etc.

**Edit:**
So the scenario is following:

WCF service runs on PC and waits for clients.
A client (which in my case is a mobile device) connects to the service.
A client ask to perform an action on a browser
Message via WCF is forwarded to the browser

I hope this scenario makes sense :)

Comment: Confusing... so WCF to call the browser and scroll the page, etc? I thought it is usually the other way around, browser calling WCF Service??

Comment: Browser is not going to be a client :)

Answer (score 2):

In general, WCF services provide *services* that clients consume.  It is probably not a good idea at all to try to force a WCF service to attempt to control anything.

WCF services should, in general, know nothing about the clients they serve.  So your service should know nothing about a browser at all.

The only scenario that might make any sense to me would be if the service provides some sort controlling information (where to navigate to, which tabs to open, etc) to a client that would then do the actual controlling itself.

Make sense?

Comment: In fact it will be the clients which will be controlling the service. Service will just forward those commands to a browser. (I have added a use case to my question)